# Panda dataframe yield error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, yield-keyword

I am trying to yield 1 row by 1 row for a panda dataframe but get an error. The dataframe is a stock price data, including daily open, close, high, low price and volume information.

The following is my code. This class will get data from MySQL database

```
class HistoricMySQLDataHandler(DataHandler):

def __init__(self, events, symbol_list):
    """
    Initialises the historic data handler by requesting
    a list of symbols.

    Parameters:
    events - The Event Queue.
    symbol_list - A list of symbol strings.
    """
    self.events = events
    self.symbol_list = symbol_list

    self.symbol_data = {}
    self.latest_symbol_data = {}
    self.continue_backtest = True       

    self._connect_MySQL()
def _connect_MySQL(self): #get stock price for symbol s 
    db_host = 'localhost'
    db_user = 'sec_user'
    db_pass = 'XXX'
    db_name = 'securities_master'
    con = mdb.connect(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name)
    for s in self.symbol_list:
       sql="SELECT * FROM daily_price where symbol= s
       self.symbol_data[s] = pd.read_sql(sql, con=con, index_col='price_date')"

def _get_new_bar(self, symbol):
    """
    Returns the latest bar from the data feed as a tuple of 
    (sybmbol, datetime, open, low, high, close, volume).
    """

    for row in self.symbol_data[symbol].itertuples():
        yield tuple(symbol, datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 
                    row[15], row[17], row[16], row[18],row[20])

def update_bars(self):
    """
    Pushes the latest bar to the latest_symbol_data structure
    for all symbols in the symbol list.
    """
    for s in self.symbol_list:
        try:
            bar = self._get_new_bar(s).__next__()
        except StopIteration:
            self.continue_backtest = False
```

In the main function:

```
# Declare the components with respective parameters
symbol_list=["GOOG"]
events=queue.Queue()
bars = HistoricMySQLDataHandler(events,symbol_list)


while True:
# Update the bars (specific backtest code, as opposed to live trading)
   if bars.continue_backtest == True:
      bars.update_bars()
   else:
      break
   time.sleep(1)
```

Data example:

```
symbol_data["GOOG"] =             
  price_date id exchange_id ticker instrument name   ...    high_price  low_price close_price adj_close_price  volume                              
  2014-03-27  29        None   GOOG      stock  Alphabet Inc Class C   ...      568.0000   552.9200      558.46          558.46    13100
```

The `update_bars` function will call `_get_new_bar` to move to next row (next day price)

My objective is to get stock price day by day (iterate rows of the dataframe) but `self.symbol_data[s]` in `_connect_MySQL` is a dataframe while in `_get_new_bar` is a generator hence I get this error

> AttributeError: `'generator'` object has no attribute `'itertuples'`

Anyone have any ideas?

I am using python 3.6. Thanks

`self.symbol_data` is a `dict`, `symbol` is a string key to get the dataframe. the data is stock price data. For example `self.symbol_data["GOOG"]` return a dataframe with google's daily stock price information index by date, each row including open, low, high, close price and volume. My goal is to iterate this price data day by day using `yield`.

`_connect_MySQL` will get data from the database
In this example, s = "GOOG" in the function

Comment: What do you expect `symbol_data[symbol]` to return? Based on the error, it returns a generator, not a panda dataframe.

Comment: I have a dataframe. symbol_data[symbol] is a dataframe. I hope to iterate this dataframe row by row using yield so that each time the function return a tuple with data from the row. Could I achieve this ?

Comment: Ok. Can you post what `self.symbol_data` looks like? And for good measure what is `symbol`? Python says that what's returned by that expression is a generator - hence the error.

Comment: self.symbol_data is a dictionary, symbol is key to get dataframe. the data is stock price data. For example self.symbol_data["GOOG"] return a dataframe with google's daily stock price information index by date, each row including open, low, high, close price and volume.  My goal is to iterate this price data day by day using yield

Comment: Please post its definition in your question. If the value of the dictionary is something like `pd.DataFrame(...)` then I would expect your code to work. Also, try printing it to see what it looks like

Comment: Let's make things easier: please **print** `type(self.symbol_data[symbol])` and display the output [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51064502/edit).

Comment: The value of this dictionary in this function (get_new_bar) is <class 'generator'> but in other function (get_data_from_MySQL) is <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>. any idea ?

Comment: @AllenHuang Well those are two different functions, and we don't know what `get_data_from_MySQL` looks like, so that's not necessarily surprising. Please edit your question to show an example of what `symbol_data` looks like. What are some example keys and values.

Comment: Assuming you're accessing these things in the same way (via `symbol_data`), the fact that they're different suggests that there are both generators and dataframes in the dictionary

Comment: @pushkin sorry for miss a lot of information. I edit the question

Comment: There is still not enough info to diagnose the issue. You say that `symbol_data["GOOG"] = ...` but the `...` is not python code. It's just the text representation of your data. What is the actual python code that represents what you stick in `symbol_data`

Comment: I add more stuff and code to the question. Don't know if this is enough ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug.
My code in other place change the dataframe to be a generator.
A stupid mistake lol

I didn't post this line in the question but this line change the datatype

```
# Reindex the dataframes
    for s in self.symbol_list:
        self.symbol_data[s] = self.symbol_data[s].reindex(index=comb_index, method='pad').iterrows()
```